# How do i get my subdomain name even if CNAME is used?

Tags: php, nginx

My site is hosted at *.example.com

```
<?php
$subdomain = array_shift((explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));
echo $subdomain ; 
?>
```

So when user visits `sub.example.com` we will get `$subdomain` as `sub`.

But if someone use CNAME for this domain by pointing `sub2.example2.com` to `sub.example.com` finally the `$subdomain` also changes to `sub2`. I don't want this.

Is there any way to solve this by php or nginx? Not by `dns_get_record´. Please do suggest new way..

Comment: No. The only way to resolve a CNAME to the name that it points to is with DNS.